# Cloudfront Hit for default behavior, but 'MISS' for path pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront

so I have one CloudFront Distribution with 2 different origins.
The default behavior goes to origin A (API Gateway A), urls matching "*appconfig" go to origin B (API Gateway B).

Both behaviours are exactly equal in all settings but the path pattern.

When I use postman to test GET, I always get `Hit from Cloudfront` and a nicely compressed gzip for the default.

When the appconfig pattern is hit, I always get `Miss from Cloudfront` and the response also isn't compressed.

How can this be given that I read each line in the `Cache Behavior Settings`carefully and made sure they are all equal?

The origin in both cases has the header 'Cache-Control: max-age= 86400,must-revalidate'.
The weird thing is that cloudfront responds very differently:

Default-Response-Headers:

[image: Default Headers]

Path-Pattern-Response-Headers:

[image: appconfig]

Comment: What's the `minimumCompressionsSize` value set in API Gateway B?

Comment: It's 256 for both gateways.